# Excel - VBA - Arranging vertically entered parameters of an ID in Horizontal fashion

Tags: vba, excel

I’m new to `VBA` and have been searching the solution from long time.
I need the data to perform `Vlookup` with another set of data having common IDs
I have data like given below.

```
ID          Status  Package
0001        ACT     Gold
0001        ACT     SSA
0001        ACT     SP
0002        ACT     Silver
0003        DIS     SSA
0003        DIS     SSB
0004        ACT     PT
0005        DIS     NP
0006        DIS     <Blank >
```

And I need it in following structure

```
ID          Status  Package1    Package 2   Package 3….
0001        ACT     Gold        SSA         SP
0002        ACT     Silver
0003        DIS     SSA         SSB
0004        ACT     PT
0005        DIS     NP
0006        DIS
```

Number of packages can vary from 0 to 15.

Also how to do reverse operation? (secondary requirement)

Tried this code (!) but result for values with 1 or no parameters was not accurate.

```
    Sub test()
Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim CLa As Range, CLb As Range, x&, Names$, ID$, Key
' Sheet1 is a Source Sheet
' Sheet3 is a Target Sheet
x = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For Each CLa In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & x)
    If Not Dic.exists(CStr(CLa.Value)) Then
        ID = CLa.Value
' Sheet1 is a Source Sheet
' Sheet3 is a Target Sheet

        For Each CLb In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & x)
            If CLb.Value = ID Then

                If Names = "" Then
                    Names = CLb.Offset(, 2).Value
                Else
                    Names = Names & "," & CLb.Offset(, 2).Value
                End If

            End If
        Next CLb

    Dic.Add ID, Names
    End If
    ID = Empty: Names = Empty
Next CLa

x = 1
For Each Key In Dic
    Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(x, 1).Value = Key
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range(Cells(x, 2), Cells(x, 4)) = Split(Dic(Key), ",")
    x = x + 1
Next Key

Sheets("Sheet3").Cells.Replace "#N/A", Replacement:=""

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: Tried using below mentioned code but result for the ID with only one parameter was not accurate.

Comment: if the IDs are sequential like that, starting at 0001, you can set up a string array of size 1 to max ID, iterate through your data row by row, building up a string for each entry which includes the status and all packages (suitably delimited) and then, once you load the array, iterate through it, writing the data back to the spreadsheet in the format you want.

Comment: Sorry  John Coleman , I have changed actual data by simplified one, the id is 12 digit long alphanumeric code and my sheet contain records of nearly 400K rows.

Comment: Shame there is not `pivot` command and `unpivot` command in Excel [as there is on MS SQL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx).

Comment: @Ralph Copy > Pastespecial (Transpose). Plus all the functionality of _pivot_ tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a simple formula:

> ="Package"&COUNTIF($A$1:$A2;A2)

It creates your matching names and then you can use a Pivot to summarize. Of course you could set up loops through for each separate ID.
The reverse is more tricky, I'd resort to something along the lines of

```
Sub ertdfgcvb()
Dim ws As Worksheet, wsex As Worksheet, k As Long, i As Long, j As Long, LastRow As Long
Set ws = Sheets("tabular form")
Set ws = Sheets("dataset form")
k = 2
LastRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow 'from the second to the last row
    j = 3 'start at Package1
    While Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, j))
        wsex.Cells(k, 1).Value2 = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value2 'copies the ID from the A column
        wsex.Cells(k, 2).Value2 = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value2 'Copies status likewise
        wsex.Cells(k, 3).Value2 = ws.Cells(i, j).Value2 'copies Package<n>
        'wsex.Cells(k, 4).Value2 = "Package" & j - 2 'copies "Package<n>"
        k = k + 1 'increases counters
        j = j + 1
    Wend
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a simple loop

```
Sub Transpose()

writeRow = 1

LastRow = Columns(1).Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow

    If Cells(i, 1).Value <> currentID Then
        'New ID
        writeRow = writeRow + 1
        currentID = Cells(i, 1).Value
        Cells(writeRow, 5).Value = currentID
        Cells(writeRow, 6).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
        Cells(writeRow, 7).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value
    Else
        'Continue from old ID
        Cells(writeRow, Rows(writeRow).Find("*", searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column + 1).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value
    End If


Next i

End Sub
```

I didn't read that you also need a reverse routine. Try these:

```
Sub Transpose()

Cells(2, 5).CurrentRegion.ClearContents
writeRow = 1

For i = 2 To Columns(1).Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    If Cells(i, 1).Value <> currentID Then
        'New ID
        writeRow = writeRow + 1
        currentID = Cells(i, 1).Value
        Cells(writeRow, 5).Value = currentID
        Cells(writeRow, 6).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
        Cells(writeRow, 7).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value
        writeCol = 8
    Else
        'Continue from old ID
        Cells(writeRow, writeCol).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value
        writeCol = writeCol + 1
    End If


Next i

End Sub

Sub ReverseTranspose()

Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion.ClearContents
writeRow = 1

For i = 2 To Columns(5).Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    For j = 7 To WorksheetFunction.Max(7, Rows(i).Find("*", searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column)
         writeRow = writeRow + 1
         currentID = Cells(i, 5).Value
         Cells(writeRow, 1).Value = currentID
         Cells(writeRow, 2).Value = Cells(i, 6).Value
         Cells(writeRow, 3).Value = Cells(i, j).Value
     Next j
Next i

End Sub
```